# Tesseract Worker.Load hangs on Vercel

Tags: next.js, tesseract, vercel

Not sure anyone can help but I have an OCR reader on my local site using Tesseract.js in my Next JS app.
It works fine on local and read smy image but when I deploy to Vercel it hangs on this line....

`await worker.load()`

Here is the whole thing

```
  const worker = createWorker()
  console.log('createWorker')

  //attempt ocr on processed image
  await worker.load()
  console.log('worker.load')

  //set language to plain english
  await worker.loadLanguage('eng')
  await worker.initialize('eng')

  //set character whitelist and disable dictionary functions that won't help us here
  await worker.setParameters({
    tessedit_char_whitelist:
      '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-/$.@| ',
    load_system_dawg: 0,
    load_freq_dawg: 0,
  })
  console.log('setParameters')

  //process editted image
  const OcrResult = await worker.recognize(imageb64)
  if (process.env.DEBUG >= 1) {
    console.log('[DEBUG] OCR: Process complete, results: ', OcrResult.data.text)
  }
```

Any quirks about Vercel that would make this not work on a test site?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might try using something like this instead, designed to use in lambda functions.

https://github.com/shelfio/aws-lambda-tesseract